# reformat text documents for easier comparison

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

For those who want to spare the reasoning behind the question jump to the **TL;DR**

Hi I'm currently reading a lot of financial annual reports of companies. While the first one is the most interesting, the documents that come after it often are the same in a lot of regards. So obviously I'm more interested in the differences between them. The documents come in pdfs which are hard to compare. So I thought it would be nice to get them as pure text and compare them with a compare tool. So thats what I did. I piped the following two pdfs through pdftotext with the below params:

[annual report for 2018](https://cdn.sea.com/webmain/static/resource/seagroup/press/2019-03-01%20-%20Form%2020-F.pdf)

[annual report for 2019](https://cdn.sea.com/webmain/static/resource/seagroup/press/2020-04-14%20-%20Form%2020-F.PDF)

```
pdftotext -enc UTF-8 -nopgbrk -eol mac
```

I then realized that compare tools seem to have problems with line breaks. So if I have the exact same sentences, but with different line breaks in both documents, it is shown as a difference. Bullet points in pdfs are transformed to different symbols in the text file which leads to differences as well. So I went into nlp and thought I might get some help there.

**TL;DR**

I just want to reformat the two snippets below in a defined way that I don't get diffs in a difftool anymore. Like lines are only 80 characters long at most and I want to have some normalized/canonical way for printing bullet points and stuff like that.

I'm currently using spacy and here is an example of two text snippets that are essentially the same but lead to a lot of diffs in difftools. So how can I reprint both snippets to a text document so that the line breaks are the same? Is there even a method to find things like two sentences are exactly the same but in one sentence there is one additional word. I would like reformat that as well without shifting the line break by one word.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
SE_2018_10k_string = '''x

“paying users” refers to the number of unique accounts through which a payment is made in our online games in a particular period. A unique
account through which payments are made in more than one online game or in more than one market is counted as more than one paying user.
“QPUs” refers to the aggregate number of paying users during the quarterly period;

x'''
doc1 = nlp(SE_2018_10k_string)
print('SE_2018_10k_string')
for token in doc1:
    print(token.text)


SE_2019_10k_string = '''●

“paying users” refers to the number of unique accounts through which a payment is made in our online games in a particular period. A unique account
through which payments are made in more than one online game or in more than one market is counted as more than one paying user. “QPUs” refers to
the aggregate number of paying users during the quarterly period;

●'''

doc2 = nlp(SE_2019_10k_string)
print('SE_2019_10k_string')
for token in doc2:
    print(token.text)

print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

Comment: Sounds like you are actually looking for the `wdiff` tool.

Comment: A more useful normalization as such might be to "unroll" paragraphs into really long lines. You don't really need NLP for this, just basic string substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way to get rid of the problems you are seeing.

If you find that you have line breaks in different places but your texts are otherwise the same, you can normalize things by removing line breaks. If you find only spaces are different, you can remove spaces, or convert any run of spaces to a single space. If bullets are an issue you can remove them or convert them to a single type of character (but how do you tell if something is a bullet in code? there is no standard way).

Appropriate normalization depends on your data, and for OCR it's typically going to just be hard.

> Is there even a method to find things like two sentences are exactly the same but in one sentence there is one additional word.

You can use edit distance metrics like Levenshtein distance to find this. It won't help you with existing diff tools though, since they show any difference.